canvas not expanding to occupy full width of window in tkinter

I am using python 3.11.9 in windows 11 home OS
Here is my relevant GUI code 
import tkinter as tk

STACKSIZE=10

class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, header_labels:tuple,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        # configuration for all Labels
        # easier to maintain than directly inputting args
        self.table_header_lbl_overwritten = {
            'master'     : self,
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 20 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'bd'         : 1,
            'bg'         : 'white',
        }
        self.no_master_table_header_lbl_overwritten = {
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 20 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'bd'         : 1,
            'bg'         : 'white',
        }
        self.big_tot_lbl = {
            'foreground' : 'green',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 22 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'bd'         : 1,
            'bg'         : 'white',
        }
        self.headers = []
        self.tot_lbl = []
        self.header_widths  = []
        self.original_header_widths  = []
        x=2
        print("creating table")
        for col, lbl in enumerate(header_labels):
            (header := tk.Label(text=lbl, **self.table_header_lbl_overwritten)).grid(row=0, column=col, sticky='nswe')
            width = header.winfo_reqwidth()
            header = tk.Label(self.master.master.master, text=lbl, **self.no_master_table_header_lbl_overwritten)
            header.place(x=x, y=2)
            x += width
            self.headers.append(header)
            self.header_widths.append(width)
            print("adding "+lbl+' of width '+str(width)+" in table")
            self.original_header_widths.append(width)
        totals_label=tk.Label(self.master.master.master,text="\nTotal Qty 0\nTotal Amt 0\nBalance 0\n",**self.big_tot_lbl)
        totals_label.place(x=x+5,y=20)
        self.tot_lbl.append(totals_label)
            
    def redraw_headers(self):
        x = 2
        print(str(self.header_widths))
        for col, header in enumerate(self.headers):
            width = self.header_widths[col]
            header.place(x=x, y=2, width=width)
            x += width
        self.tot_lbl[0].place(x=x+5, y=20)

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="tkinter window", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(**kwargs)
#Fixed Entries
        header_labels = ('','Description','Quantity','Rate','Amount','')
#FONT SETTINGS
        self.gui_btn_look = {
            'foreground' : 'red',
            'relief'     : 'groove',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'padx'       : 0,
            'pady'       : 0,
        }
        self.gui_info_lbl_look = {
            'foreground' : 'green',
            'relief'     : 'solid',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
        }
        self.gui_lbl_look = {
            'foreground' : 'black',
            'relief'     : 'flat',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'padx'       : 0,
            'pady'       : 0,
            'borderwidth': 1,
        }
        self.gui_entry_look = {
            'foreground' : 'blue',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'highlightbackground'   :"black",
            'highlightthickness'    : 2,
            'highlightcolor'        :"blue",
            'insertbackground'      :"blue",
            'insertwidth'           :3,
        }
        self.pending_lbl_look = {
            'foreground' : 'black',
            'relief'     : 'groove',
            'font'       : 'Arial 18 bold',
            'padx'       : 5,
            'pady'       : 0,
        }
#GUI 
#bill number
        self.first_row_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        self.first_row_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='W')
        self.lbl_ser_num=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text="Sr No:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_ser_num.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.txt_ser_num=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text='1',**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.txt_ser_num.grid(column=1,row=0)
# print button
        self.btn_print=tk.Button(self.first_row_frame,text="Print",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.btn_print.grid(column=2,row=0,padx=5)
# new bill button
        self.btn_print=tk.Button(self.first_row_frame,text="New Bill",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.btn_print.grid(column=3,row=0)
# cash field
        self.cash_lbl=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text="Cash:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.cash_lbl.grid(column=4,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.cash=tk.Entry(self.first_row_frame,width=5,text='0',**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.cash.grid(column=5,row=0)
# Time label
        self.txt_date=tk.Label(self.first_row_frame,text='Sunday, December 22, 2024 07:36:02 AM',**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.txt_date.grid(column=6,row=0,padx=5)
        self.btn_pending=tk.Button(self.first_row_frame,text="<",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.btn_pending.grid(column=7,row=0)
#cancel button
        self.cancel_btn=tk.Button(self.first_row_frame,text="Cancel",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.cancel_btn.grid(column=8,row=0,padx=5)
        self.go_to_printed_btn=tk.Button(self.first_row_frame,text=">",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.go_to_printed_btn.grid(column=9,row=0)
# Second row 
        self.second_row_frame=tk.Frame(self)
        self.second_row_frame.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='W',pady=5)
# Goods return field
        self.lbl_return=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="GR:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_return.grid(column =0, row =0)
        self.return_value=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=5,text='0',**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.return_value.grid(column=1,row=0,padx=(0,5))
#description field
        self.txt_desc=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=10,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_desc.grid(column=2,row=0)
# rate field
        self.lbl_rate=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Rate:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_rate.grid(column=5,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.txt_rate=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=4,text='',**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_rate.grid(column=6,row=0)
        self.txt_rate.focus_set()
# quantity field
        self.lbl_qty=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Qty:",**self.gui_lbl_look)
        self.lbl_qty.grid(column=3,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.txt_qty=tk.Entry(self.second_row_frame,width=3,**self.gui_entry_look)
        self.txt_qty.grid(column=4,row=0)
#Item amount
        self.lbl_amt=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text="Amount:",**self.gui_lbl_look,bd=1,anchor="e",justify="right")
        self.lbl_amt.grid(column=7,row=0,padx=(5,0))
        self.txt_amt=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text='0',width=5,**self.gui_lbl_look,bd=1,anchor="w",justify="left")
        self.txt_amt.grid(column=8,row=0)
#Add to table button
        self.btn_add=tk.Button(self.second_row_frame,text="Add",**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.btn_add.grid(column=9,row=0,padx=5)
#Pending label
        self.txt_pending=tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text='pending:',**self.gui_lbl_look,anchor="w",justify="left")
        self.txt_pending.grid(column=10,row=0)
        self.pending_label_stack=[]
        for number in range(0,STACKSIZE):
            self.pending_label_stack.append(tk.Label(self.second_row_frame,text='-',**self.pending_lbl_look,anchor="w",justify="left"))
            self.pending_label_stack[number].grid(column=11+number,row=0)
# Fourth row of Table
        self.content_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='nswe')
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.content_frame,bg='sky blue')
        scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.content_frame,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview,width=50)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.table_frame=tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nws')
        self.table_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e:self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.frame_id=self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.table_frame,anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nswe")
        scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="ns")
        self.table_frame.trial_var=0
        self.table = Table(self.table_frame,header_labels)
        self.table.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nswe')
#virtual keyboard
        self.keyboard_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.keyboard_frame.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='se',padx=(10,55))
        self.info_label=tk.Label(self,text=" New bill:ctrl+N \n Cancel:x \n GR:F1 \n Rate:F3 \n Qty:F2 \n Cash:F4 \n Print:F10 ",**self.gui_info_lbl_look)
        self.info_label.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='ne',padx=(10,55))
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        for numbers in range(1,11):
            self.add_number_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text=str(numbers%10),**self.gui_btn_look)
            self.add_number_button.grid(column=int(numbers-1)%3,row=int((numbers-1)/3))
        self.clear_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.clear_button.grid(column=1,row=3,columnspan=2,sticky='e')
        self.enter_button=tk.Button(self.keyboard_frame,text='Enter',**self.gui_btn_look)
        self.enter_button.grid(column=0,row=4,columnspan=3,sticky='')
#maximizing table area
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.content_frame.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.content_frame.rowconfigure(0,weight=2)
        # update so we can get the current dimensions           
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.state('zoomed')
        #FOR LINUX self.attributes('-zoomed',True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application().mainloop()

Here, the function redraw_headers is used when the table cells expand on addition of row or contract on deletion of row . The purpose is to show that this function aligns the headers with table contents .
I want the blue canvas with scroll bar to occupy full width of window . How can I do that ?
Here is the current window screenshot


I am talking about about the empty space next to scroll bar in this post .
Please let me know if any other detail is needed.
Thanks.

I see the issue - the canvas isn't expanding to fill the window width. This is a common tkinter layout problem that can be fixed by adjusting the grid configuration. Here are the key changes needed:
# Fourth row of Table
        self.content_frame=tk.Frame(self,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        self.content_frame.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky='nswe')
        
        # Make content_frame expand horizontally
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.canvas=tk.Canvas(self.content_frame,bg='sky blue')
        scrollbar=tk.Scrollbar(self.content_frame,orient="vertical",command=self.canvas.yview,width=50)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        
        # Make canvas expand within content_frame
        self.content_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.content_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.table_frame=tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.table_frame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nws')
        

The main changes are:

Added self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) to make the main window's first column expandable
Added self.content_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) to make the canvas expand within the content frame

This might solve your problem :)

thanks Chihaya Yuka for logical explanation . In my code above - it seems if I remove line "self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)" then it becomes ok .
